# Recovering GRUB/Arch Linux after installing Windows 7

Tags: windows, linux, grub, arch-linux, bootloader

So on my desktop I have Arch Linux installed but I need to dual boot with Windows 7. After installing Windows 7, it's bootloader takes over and the original GRUB is gone. Now, I've done this before and took notes, but apparently it doesn't want to work. Here's what I have, assuming /dev/sda1 is where Arch Linux is installed:

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount -o bind /sys /mnt/sys
mount -t proc /proc /mnt/proc
chroot /dev/mnt/
grub-install /dev/sda
```

After I run that and reboot, it still goes to the Windows loader, so I can still only run Windows. Any idea on what I can do to get around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GRUB has an internal way to do it, which I've found may work when grub-install does not. It requires an existing `/boot/grub`, which you should have lying around.

On a LiveCD, open up the GRUB CLI (`su -c grub`) and run:

```
find /boot/grub/stage1
root (hdX,Y)
setup (hdX)
```

Comment: And that'll basically do all of the magic?

Comment: @Chiggins It should. GRUB knows how exactly to locate its own stuff within most any partition type, and shouldn't require any extra mounting.

Comment: Alright cool, thanks for that. I'll give it a shot when I get home.

Comment: Yeah I  tried to run that but it didn't work as expected :\ Still booting into the Windows bootloader